# dell xps laptop windows 8 can connect to wireless perfectly except one network that everyone else can connect to

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, router, connection, wifi-configuration

Purchased a new Dell XPS laptop. Can connect to the wireless at work, at clients, at the shopping center but not to my home network. the network is not even visible.
at home my ipad connect, my kids windows laptops connect and the phones can connect, just not this new laptop.
Del XPS.

I have tried:
creating the wireless network manually
deleting all networks from command prompt
deleting the drivers
updating the drivers
flushing DNS
restarting
windows updates
etc etc

now the actual wireless router is a mikrotik 1W wireless. my problem is that this was setup before we moved in and in the roof somewhere but no idea and I dont want to fiddle cause we have 7 or 8 people in the family all using the connection fine.

Any ideas what this could be? I fiddled with some of the settings in device manager for the wireless network card but nothing seems to work.

as mentioned i can see and connect to any other wireless network, just this one is an issue. more puzzling is that any other device can connect to the network just fine.

any ideas appreciated.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Which kind of encryption configuration is used on you WiFi?  Windows 8 doesn't like WEP.

Comment: Hi @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007. thanks for help. WPA2-Personal
TKIP

Comment: more information about the 802.11 mode please

Comment: is it possible that your wifi router is set up to only assign 8 ip addresses, so you, being the 9th person can't get on? We had that problem in our house after getting a new device and every time we restarted the router, one person would not be able to connect.